# Can't insert array with a variable in Laravel Controller

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to insert an array in my database with a variable member_id.

HTML

My Controller

This work without member_id

```
 foreach ($request->moreFields as $key => $value) {
                Permit::create($value);
  }
```

This doesn't work with member id

```
foreach ($request->moreFields as $key => $value) {
            Permit::create([    
                'member_id' => $member_id,
                'license_type' => $request->license_type[$i],
                'license_number' => $request->license_number[$i],
                'registration_date' => $request->registration_date[$i],
                'expiration_date' => $request->expiration_date[$i],
            ]);
        }
```

I'm trying to insert an array with a variable so that it can have relationships in the member's table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just modify the array before insert it to Database like [`array_merge()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php),

```php
foreach ($request->moreFields as $key => $value) {
    Permit::create(array_merge($value, ['member_id' => $member_id]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the rest of the code to be sure but my guess is you're using a closure which removes `$member_id` form the scope of your loop. If that's the case, then the **use** keyword will allow you to access variables outside of the scope of the closure. For example -

```php
function () use ($member_id) { // pass $member_id into scope of closure
    foreach ($request->moreFields as $key => $value) {
        Permit::create([    
            'member_id' => $member_id,
            'license_type' => $request->license_type[$i],
            'license_number' => $request->license_number[$i],
            'registration_date' => $request->registration_date[$i],
            'expiration_date' => $request->expiration_date[$i],
        ]);
    }
};
```

Comment: \DB::transaction(function () use($request,$member_id, $license){ actually i have in db::transaction

Comment: i tried same as here https://www.positronx.io/laravel-dynamically-add-or-remove-multiple-input-fields-with-jquery/ but want to add member_id

Comment: Then I guess member_id isn't returning anything, and if there are no errors then it's failing gracefully. If this is an AJAX call what is the response in dev tools? And how is member_id defined?